# Login System Hash Salt

Tags: php, security, authentication, hash, salt

I am rewriting a PHP Login system and I just faced this

```
function createSalt()
{
    $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($string, 0, 3);
}
$salt = createSalt();
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);
```

Actualy I never worked with salting before, I searched a bit and found it useful.
But my answer is, Is this a good way to work with salt?
Wouldn't `$string = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true))` be better?

And what about returning only 3 characters of the hash? I really don't get it.

What you think?

Comment: It's a sub-atomic bit better than just plain hashing. But there are better tools like [phppass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) or [PBKDF2](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm) which are more secure. You just have to make sure that whatever new function you are using that you can still validate the old hashes (and you have to detect if the hash is old or new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer sha1 or sha256, md5 is super-outdated, the sha-functions are way better. But this is my opinion, choose what you want.

What is really important in this case is the salt. A salt is always stored in plaintext together with the hash and is used to improve the length of a password (if you want to hash the password, might be something else of course) to prevent attacks based on rainbow/lookup tables. This is no protection against cracking the password by using bruteforce (which works quite well against md5, so use sha256 which is harder to crack).

Therefore it is totally unimportant if you use 32 random chars for the hash, or something like md5(mt_rand()) - important is the length. I would use something like

```
$hash = md5(mt_rand()) . md5(mt_rand());
```

md5() results in 32 bytes string, based on a random number (mt_rand() is better then uniqueid()). With this simpel line you get a very "strong" hash which should secure every password against rainbow tables.

Comment: __None of these algorithms (md5, sha1, sha256) is suitable for password hashing, and using them is dangerous__; they weren't suitable in 2012 either. The only correct option here is a real password hashing algorithm, like bcrypt, scrypt, or Argon2i.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using PHP's [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) instead of reinventing the wheel. It is specifically designed for password hashing, and offers hash algorithms suited for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the given function `createSalt()` - mainly for the same reasons as you.

My approach to this would be

```
define(SALT_LENGTH,32);

function createSalt()
{
  $string='';
  for ($i=0;$i<SALT_LENGTH;$i++) $string.=chr(rand(0,255));
  return $string;
}
```

A good salt is a random byte sequence - no MD5 or SHA1 makes any sense, as there is nothing to hash!

Answer (score 0):

I no master PHP programmer but I've been working on the same hash script for a login system.

Im storing it on GitHub - https://github.com/revitalagency/PHP5-Salt-Super-Admin

I created my hash using...

```
hash_hmac('sha256', $_POST['pass'], GLOBAL_SALT);
```

GLOBAL_SALT is defined in a config file not in the DB for extra protection.